# My WiFi Adapter isn't being Identified

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, additional-drivers

New to Ubuntu, my wifi was working before but I tried to connect to the internet today, but it does not show any WiFi adapter or signs of WiFi. tries lspci here is the output:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)enter code here
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d13 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
```

cannot find network adapter btw using Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

But the WiFi works in windows 8.1

here is lshw -C network output:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 48:ba:4e:f5:9e:02
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4104000-b4104fff memory:b4100000-b4103fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:88:6f:3f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:88:6f:3f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: enxac7debe3e10b
       serial: ac:7d:eb:e3:e1:0b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.0.101 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Link to PasteBin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hdYvZkXGfQ/

Comment: Try resetting BIOS to defaults.  I see an Intel bluetooth device in your script results so the wifi is going to be Intel and likely uses iwlwifi kernel module if it ever shows in lspci results

Comment: I have done that already, but it doesn't solve the problem. @Jeremy31

Comment: Does wifi work in a Live USB?

Comment: @Jeremy31 could you clarify?